# Erlang, why is my pattern matching not working for equations inside equations?

Tags: recursion, erlang, pattern-matching

I have an evaluation function (expr_eval/1) which should evaluate an 
expression  and return a 
number. As of this moment my function is returning valid numbers for equations such as:

```
expr_eval({plus,{num, 17},{num,10}}) → 27
```

but not for this:

```
expr_eval({mul,{plus,{num,5},{num,8}},{num,3}}) → 39
```

My Function:

```
   expr_eval({mul, {num,A}, {num,B}}) ->A*B;
   expr_eval({plus, {num,A}, {num,B}}) ->A+B;
   expr_eval({minus, {num,A},{num,B}}) ->A-B;
   expr_eval({_,_,_})->nothing_matched.
```

I understand that it is only taking the patterns as it is, but how can I fix this problem?  I could hard code it and add the below code to my function and the above equation works fine, but it wouldn't apply to other equations.(e.g. expr_eval({minus,{plus,{num,5},{num,8}},{num,3}}) → 8)

```
expr_eval({mul, {plus,{num,A},{num,B}},{num,C}}) ->(A+B)*C;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well I believe it must be recursive function, something like

```
expr({num,X}) -> X;
expr({plus, X, Y})  -> expr(X) + expr(Y);
expr({minus, X, Y}) -> expr(X) - expr(Y);
expr({mul,X, Y}) -> expr(X)*expr(Y);
expr(Any) -> io:format("Dont know what to do with ~p~n",[Any]).
```